# How to translate "morning breath" into Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation

Would “*mane spiritum*” / “*mane anima*” translate accurately to morning breath please?

I am very new to Latin.

I would be very grateful for any help moving forwards please as there are a number of short phrases I would like to translate.

Answer (score 7):

In *Naturalis historia* 28.194, Pliny the Elder gives, as a remedy for bad breath and other lung-related issues, a decoction of butter and an equal amount of Attic honey or larch resin:

> purulentas autem exulcerationes pectoris pulmonisque et a pulmone graveolentiam halituss butyrum efficacissime iuvat cum pari modo mellis Attici decoctum, donec rufescat, et matutinis sumptum ad mensuram lingulae; quidam pro melle laricis resinam addere maluere.

The relevant phrase is *graveolentia hālitūs ā pulmōne*, 'offensive smell of the breath from the lung'; this could be simplified to ***graveolentia hālitūs***.

In *Ars amatoria* 1.521, Ovid advises would-be lovers to watch out for bad breath:

> nec male odorati sit tristis anhelitus oris.

So 'bad breath' here is *tristis anhēlitus male odōrātī ōris*, 'the repulsive breath of a malodorous mouth.' Since the *Oxford Latin dictionary* indicates that *anhēlitus* by itself  means 'malodorous breath,' you could simplify this to ***anhēlitus ōris*** or even just ***anhēlitus***.

For 'morning,' you want an *adjective* that means 'of or belonging to the morning,' such as ***mātūtīnus***. (Note that *māne*, which you've used, is an adverb or a noun, not an adjective.)

So 'morning breath' could be ***mātūtīna graveolentia hālitūs***, 'morning-time offensive smell of the breath' or ***mātūtīnus anhēlitus*** (***ōris***), 'morning time malodorous breath (of the mouth).'

You could even 'transfer' the adjectives in each phrase, giving ***graveolentia mātūtīnī hālitūs*** and ***anhēlitus mātūtīnī ōris*** (in this case, though, the word *ōris* can't be omitted).

Comment: Ah fantastic, this is where I was struggling. The phrase is to be used on a coffee cup and is to be a play on words, very roughly along the lines of (coffee gives me) morning breath (life/wakes me up) (but without the actual written ref to coffee if this makes sense). So with these two answers would “matutinus spiritus” make sense please?

Comment: Or matutinus spiro?

Comment: @mae What a great idea for a coffee cup!  I think _matutinus spiritus_  would work (a combination of cnread's and luchonacho's answers).  Although it doesn't convey the sense of *bad* breath, it does convey the other senses you're after: a breath, an animating spirit, a smell, and even inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

The nominative of "breath" is *spiritus*. *Spiritum* is in the accusative case. 
So if we were to understand "morning breath" as "breath of the morning", then a more appropriate translation would be *spiritus mane*. *Anima* is also possible, as in *anima mane*.

Less figuratively words for breath are *[halitus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/halitus#Latin)* and *[anhelitus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anhelitus#Latin)*. These two derive in Spanish words which mean breath (as in e.g. bad breath).

Comment: Ah, but now I’m wondering, why manis instead of mane? I apologise if this is all really basic and thank you ever so much for your help 

Comment: @mae I updated the answer. I got that wrong. _mane_ is indeclinable, so regardless of the case (most of nouns in Latin are declinables; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_declension)), morning is always _mane_. So, considering that morning breath is an example of two nouns together, where "morning" is a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), and that these can usually be rewritten with a preposition (in this case, "of"), I'm trying to translate the phrase "breath of the morning". If that is not the meaning you intend, then this might not be good.